# Developing Generic AXI4 Peripheral with Chisel

Tags: fpga, chisel, rocket-chip

I want to develop a generic AXI4 peripheral with Chisel. Can I use the Rocket-Chip's AMBA library for this purpose? I could only find the document in the link below on this subject;

[MMIO-Peripherals](https://chipyard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Customization/MMIO-Peripherals.html)

However, the example in this document is designed to be used with the Rocket-Chip. I want to develop a standalone AXI4 peripheral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question mentions following:

- *I want to develop a standalone Axi4 peripheral*

When I had started developing AXI4 interfaces in Chisel, my starting point was the [Chisel official documentation](https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/docs/explanations/dataview.html) where they start with a typical Verilog peripheral using AXI4 for a write channel as following:

```
 module my_module(
  
// Write Channel
  input        AXI_AWVALID,
  output       AXI_AWREADY,
  input [3:0]  AXI_AWID,
  input [19:0] AXI_AWADDR,
  input [1:0]  AXI_AWLEN,
  input [1:0]  AXI_AWSIZE,
  // ...
);
```

To this end, the Chisel Bundle would be as following:

```
class VerilogAXIBundle(val addrWidth: Int) extends Bundle {
  val AWVALID = Output(Bool())
  val AWREADY = Input(Bool())
  val AWID = Output(UInt(4.W))
  val AWADDR = Output(UInt(addrWidth.W))
  val AWLEN = Output(UInt(2.W))
  val AWSIZE = Output(UInt(2.W))
  // The rest of AW and other AXI channels here
}

// Instantiated as
class my_module extends RawModule {
  val AXI = IO(new VerilogAXIBundle(20))
}
```

Although the aforementioned example is trivial but this was helpful for me to start writing generic AXI4 interfaces in Chisel.

Having said that, I have also used some of the following resources to develop AXI interfaces in Chisel:

- [AXI-in-Chisel](https://github.com/maltanar/axi-in-chisel)
- [AXI interfaces-in-Chisel](https://github.com/maltanar/fpga-tidbits/tree/master/src/main/scala/fpgatidbits/interfaces)

Comment: I have developed an AXI library on @BZKN's suggestion. You can download it following github link

https://github.com/yamak/axi-nodes

Comment: this is cool stuff....and really helpful for current and future developers who will read this post :). I have already starred on my github.